# Poker calculations on winrate

Tags: probability, statistics, poker

Just to learn I'm doing some calculations on my poker results.
I'm trying to figure out the probability of given winrate.

The available statistics I got in my database are:

> Hands: $30 000$
>
> Winrate: $2$ bets per $100$ hands
>
> Expected winrate (what our winrate would be if we had gained all of our EV) : $8$ bets per $100$ hands
>
> StdDev: $8$ bets per $100$ hands

What's the probability of our winrate per $100$ hands being less than $2$ given that our expected winrate is $8$?

I'm thinking like this:

Central limit theorem can be applied and therefore normalized

Use this formula: $t = \dfrac{2-8}{8/(3k^{0.5})}$

And then look up $t$ in a $z$-table? ($t$ will be very close to $z$ because of the large sample).

Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine, except that I don't know what $k$ is.

Standard error $=\frac{0.08}{\sqrt{30000}}$,  $z=\frac{0.08-0.02}{\text{standard error}}$

Comment: Sorry typed the formula a bit sloppy, was supposed to be 30k = 30 000.

And I missread the numbers in my database. Stddv per 100 hands is 80. Also found without per 100 hands, which is 8. How come it's not 80/100?